# git finding duplicate commits (by patch-id)

Tags: git, duplicates, commit

I'd like a recipe for finding duplicated changes.
patch-id is likely to be the same but the commit attributes may not be.

This seems to be an intended use of patch-id:

> git patch-id --help
>
> IOW, you can use this thing to look for likely duplicate commits.

I imagine that stringing together "git log", "git patch-id" and uniq
could do the job badly but if someone has an command that does the
job well, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: This is a fascinating feature. Out of curiosity, how far back in the past are you intending to look? I could see some creative integration uses for this (i.e. "my contributor doesn't know how to rebase"), but over long history it would be less effective...?

Comment: The issue appeared in a week long history of a single branch, so my use case was quite gentle (git log -p was enough).  The patch-id comment got me curious though...  Searching all history could be painful.

Comment: `git patch-id` should now *properly* reports all differences (attributes or binary) with Git 2.39 (Q2 2022). See my [updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63674369/6309).

Answer (score 12):

Because the duplicate changes are likely to be not on the same branch (except when there are reverts in between them), you could use [git cherry](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry):

```
git cherry [-v] [<upstream> [<head> [<limit>]]]
```

Where `upstream` would be the branch to check for duplicates of changes in `head`.

Answer (score 12):

For looking for duplicates of a specific commit, this may work for you.

First, determine the patch id of the target commit:

```sh
$ THE_COMMIT_REF_OR_SHA_YOURE_SEEKING_DUPES_OF='7a3e67c'
$ git show $THE_COMMIT_REF_OR_SHA_YOURE_SEEKING_DUPES_OF | git patch-id
f6ea51cd6acd30cd627ce1a56e2733c1777d5b52 7a3e67ce38dbef471889d9f706b9161da7dc5cf3
```

The first SHA is the patch-id.  Next, list the patch ids for every commit and filter out any that match:

```sh
$ for c in $(git rev-list --all); do git show $c | git patch-id; done | grep 'f6ea51cd6acd30cd627ce1a56e2733c1777d5b52'
f6ea51cd6acd30cd627ce1a56e2733c1777d5b52 5028e2b5500bd5f4637531e337e17b73f5d0c0b1
f6ea51cd6acd30cd627ce1a56e2733c1777d5b52 7a3e67ce38dbef471889d9f706b9161da7dc5cf3
f6ea51cd6acd30cd627ce1a56e2733c1777d5b52 929c66b5783a0127a7689020d70d398f095b9e00
```

All together, with a few extra flags, and in the form of a [utility script](https://gist.github.com/capnslipp/d0ac4dd125d66b6f42ed):

```sh
test ! -z "$1" && TARGET_COMMIT_SHA="$1" || TARGET_COMMIT_SHA="HEAD"

TARGET_COMMIT_PATCHID=$(
git show --patch-with-raw "$TARGET_COMMIT_SHA" |
    git patch-id |
    cut -d' ' -f1
)
MATCHING_COMMIT_SHAS=$(
for c in $(git rev-list --all); do
    git show --patch-with-raw "$c" |
        git patch-id
done |
    fgrep "$TARGET_COMMIT_PATCHID" |
    cut -d' ' -f2
)

echo "$MATCHING_COMMIT_SHAS"
```

Usage:

```sh
$ git list-dupe-commits 7a3e67c
5028e2b5500bd5f4637531e337e17b73f5d0c0b1
7a3e67ce38dbef471889d9f706b9161da7dc5cf3
929c66b5783a0127a7689020d70d398f095b9e00
```

It isn't terribly speedy, but for most repos should get the job done *(just measured 36 seconds for a repo with 826 commits and a 158MB .git dir on a 2.4GHz Core 2 Duo)*.

Comment: I may be the only one confused, but just in case, "target-commit" is not a literal; replace it with the SHA of the commit you want to get a patch ID for.

Comment: @Jimothy Yep, or a branch name or a tag name (any ref, I guess).  I'll see if I can make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 4):

I have a draft that works on a toy repo, but as it keeps the 
patch->commit map in memory it might have problems on large repos:

```
# print commit pairs with the same patch-id
for c in $(git rev-list HEAD); do \
    git show $c | git patch-id; done \
| perl -anle '($p,$c)=@F;print "$c $s{$p}" if $s{$p};$s{$p}=$c'
```

The output should be pairs of commits with the same patch-id
(3 duplicates A B C come out as "A B" then "B C").

Change the git rev-list command to restrict the commits checked:

```
git log --format=%H HEAD somefile
```

Append "| xargs git show" to view the commits in detail,
or "| xargs git show -s --oneline" for a summary:

```
0569473 add 6-8
5e56314 add 6-8 again
bece3c3 comment
e037ed6 add comment again
```

It turns out patch-id didn't work in my original case as
there were additional changes in that later commit.
"git log -S" was more useful.

Comment: If you want to look at just at raw diffs between a commit and its parent, you could do something like `git diff $c~1 $c | git patch-id`. It's going to misbehave on merge commits. Following both merge parents is a more complex problem.

Comment: It looks like patch-id finds the same diff?    $ git diff HEAD~1 HEAD | git patch-id
    3318362fa07e580.. 000000000000..
    $ git show HEAD | git patch-id
    3318362fa07e580.. c397c4cdc426..

Comment: @bsb Are you sure you wanted to write `git show $c | git patch-id`? `git show` prints metadata, but `git patch-id` needs a patch as input...

Comment: @daniel-alder, I think I need the `show` rather than `diff` since that allows the Perl to print the duplicate commits (otherwise I just get a whole lot of zero shas). [The code](http://tinyurl.com/git-patch-id) skips non-diff input (although perhaps older versions don't suppose this, what version are you using?)

Comment: @bsb thx for this explanation. I checked again and saw the diff. `git show` and `git patch-id` seem to cooperate nicely, but only for normal commits. for merges it doesn't seem to show any diff, that was my problem. tested with 1.7.10.4 and 1.9.1

Answer (score 3):

To search for duplicate commits of commit `$hash`, excluding merge commits:

```
git rev-list --no-merges --all | xargs -r git show | git patch-id \
    | grep ^$(git show $hash|git patch-id|cut -c1-40) | cut -c42-80 \
    | xargs -r git show -s --oneline
```

For searching the duplicate of a merge commit `$mergehash`, replace `$(git show $hash|git patch-id|cut -c1-40)` above by one of the two patch IDs (1st column) given by `git diff-tree -m -p $mergehash | git patch-id`. They correspond to the diffs of the merge commit with each of its two parents.

To find duplicates of all commits, excluding merge commits:

```
git rev-list --no-merges --all | xargs -r git show | git patch-id \
    | sort | uniq -w40 -D | cut -c42-80 \
    | xargs -r git log --no-walk --pretty=format:"%h %ad %an (%cn) %s" --date-order --date=iso
```

The search for duplicate commits can be extended or limited by changing the arguments to `git rev-list`, which accepts numerous options. For example, to limit the search to a specific branch specify its name instead of the option `--all`; or to search in the last 100 commits pass the arguments `HEAD ^HEAD~100`.

Note that these commands are fast since they use no shell loop, and batch-process commits.

To include merge commits, remove the option `--no-merges`, and replace `xargs -r git show` by `xargs -r -L1 git diff-tree -m -p`. This is much slower because `git diff-tree` is executed once per commit.

Explanation:

- The first line generates a map of the patch IDs with the commit hashes (2-column data, of 40 characters each).
- The second line only keeps commit hashes (2nd column) corresponding to the duplicate patch IDs (1st column).
- The last line prints custom information about the duplicate commits.

Answer (score 2):

The nifty command suggested by [bsb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1462529/bsb) requires a couple of small tweaks:

(1) Instead of `git show`, which runs `git diff-tree --cc`, the command should use

```
    git diff-tree -p
```

Otherwise `git patch-id` generates spurious null SHA1 hashes.

(2) When the pipe to `xargs` is used, `xargs` should have the `-L 1` argument.  Otherwise a triplicated commit will not be paired with an equivalent commit.

Here's an alias to go in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
dup = "!f() { for c in $(git rev-list HEAD); do git diff-tree -p $c | git patch-id; done | perl -anle '($p,$c)=@F;print \"$c $s{$p}\" if $s{$p};$s{$p}=$c' | xargs -L 1 git show -s --oneline; }; f" # "git dup" lists duplicate commits
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to do this on windows powershell the equivalent command to unagi's answer is:

```
git rev-list --no-merges --all  | %{&git.exe show $_} | 
  git patch-id | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames PatchId, Commit | 
  Group-Object PatchId | Where-Object count -gt 1 | 
  %{$_.group.Commit + " "}
```

Gives an output like:

```
1605e0e1e13d7b3f456c20432d8edec664ca7117
1e8efa8f2f01962a2c08fd25caf687d330383428

b45b6db084b27ae420ac8e9cf6511110ebb46513
4a2e1e3ba5a9a1d5db1d00343813e1404f6124e2
```

With the duplicate commit hashes grouped together.

CAUTION: On my repo this was a slow command so be sure to filter the call to rev-list appropriately!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use a recent version of Git (2.39 or more)

The `git log --format=%H` mentioned by the [OP bsb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1462529/bsb)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11642739/6309) is not always unique.

That is because, before Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), the patch-id computation did not ignore the "incomplete last line" marker like whitespaces.

See [commit 82a6201](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82a62015a7b55a56f779b9ddfb98a3b0552d2bb4) (19 Aug 2020) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5122614](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51226147d16d59243957cb3bc1b2313f9f740725), 24 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`patch-id`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82a62015a7b55a56f779b9ddfb98a3b0552d2bb4): ignore newline at end of file in `diff_flush_patch_id()`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Tilman Vogel</sup>
> <sup>Initial-test-by: Tilman Vogel</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> Whitespace is ignored when calculating patch IDs.
> This is done by removing all whitespace from diff lines before hashing them, including a newline at the end of a file.
> **If that newline is missing, however, diff reports that fact in a separate line containing "\ No newline at end of file\n", and this marker is hashed like a context line.**
>
> This goes against our goal of making patch IDs independent of whitespace.
>
> Use the same heuristic that [2485eab55cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2485eab55cc0dcab34311ecd0ac52038aa9d9db4) (git-patch-id: do not trip over "no newline" markers, 2011-02-17) added to [`git patch-id`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/82a62015a7b55a56f779b9ddfb98a3b0552d2bb4/Documentation/git-patch-id.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id))</sup> instead and skip diff lines that start with a backslash and a space and are longer than twelve characters.

---

> A "patch ID" is nothing but a SHA-1 of the diff associated with a patch, with whitespace and line numbers ignored

Actually, [`git patch-id`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id) will evolve with  Git 2.39 (Q4 2022).

A new "`--include-whitespace`" option is added to "[`git patch-id`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/160314e62537274d88c939bed957f623cda13da4/Documentation/git-patch-id.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id))</sup>, and existing bugs in the internal `patch-id` logic that did not match what "`git patch-id`" produces have been corrected with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022).

See [commit 0d32ae8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d32ae8d7ffab444a83ce1db11e5341a95d109dd), [commit 2871f4d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2871f4d447214874e13cf764ab3a170c9d844ca2), [commit 93105ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93105aba6c4c8608b10c8ebe14b2313b3d347124), [commit 0df19eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0df19eb9d905ff9b6115139106d98d8f0a8a9046), [commit 51276c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51276c1832d64d3b8f4dfc06c3ef21bf74f1916e), [commit 0570be7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0570be79ead35e47e29ee2587e2c8ea47c091d49) (24 Oct 2022) by [Jerry Zhang (`jerry-skydio`)](https://github.com/jerry-skydio).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit 160314e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/160314e62537274d88c939bed957f623cda13da4), 30 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`builtin`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2871f4d447214874e13cf764ab3a170c9d844ca2): patch-id: add `--verbatim` as a command mode
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jerry Zhang</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>

> There are situations where the user might not want the default setting where patch-id strips all whitespace.
> They might be working in a language where white space is syntactically important, or they might have CI testing that enforces strict whitespace linting.
> In these cases, a whitespace change would result in the patch fundamentally changing, and thus deserving of a different id.
>
> Add a new mode that is exclusive of `--stable` and `--unstable` called `--verbatim`.
> It also corresponds to the config `patchid.verbatim = true`.
> In this mode, the stable algorithm is used and whitespace is not stripped from the patch text.
>
> Users git of `--unstable` mainly care about compatibility with old versions, which unstripping the whitespace would break.
> Thus there isn't a use case for the combination of `--verbatim` and `--unstable`, and we don't expose this so as to not add maintenance burden.
>
> fixes https://github.com/Skydio/revup/issues/2

`git patch-id` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2871f4d447214874e13cf764ab3a170c9d844ca2/Documentation/git-patch-id.txt#L33-L38):

> ### `--verbatim`
>
> Calculate the patch-id of the input as it is given, do not strip
> any whitespace.
>
> This is the default if `patchid.verbatim` is true.

But that is not all.
From the OP:

> I'd like a recipe for finding duplicated changes. patch-id is likely to be the same but the commit attributes may not be.

That is also fixed with Git 2.39:

> ### [`patch-id`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93105aba6c4c8608b10c8ebe14b2313b3d347124): fix `patch-id` for mode changes
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jerry Zhang</sup>

> Currently patch-id as used in rebase and cherry-pick does not account for file modes if the file is modified.
> One consequence of this is that if you have a local patch that changes modes, but upstream has applied an outdated version of the patch that doesn't include that mode change, "[`git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/93105aba6c4c8608b10c8ebe14b2313b3d347124/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> will drop your local version of the patch along with your mode changes.
> It also means that internal `patch-id` doesn't produce the same output as the builtin, which does account for mode changes due to them being part of diff output.
>
> Fix by adding mode to the patch-id if it has changed, in the same format that would be produced by diff, so that it is compatible with builtin patch-id.

And last difference which was not properly detected/reported:

> ### [`builtin`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0df19eb9d905ff9b6115139106d98d8f0a8a9046): patch-id: fix patch-id with binary diffs
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jerry Zhang</sup>

> "[`git patch-id`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0df19eb9d905ff9b6115139106d98d8f0a8a9046/Documentation/git-patch-id.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id))</sup> currently does not produce correct output if the incoming diff has any binary files.
> Add logic to `get_one_patchid` to handle the different possible styles of binary diff.
> This attempts to keep resulting patch-ids identical to what would be produced by the counterpart logic in [`diff.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0df19eb9d905ff9b6115139106d98d8f0a8a9046/diff.c), that is it produces the id by hashing the `a` and `b` oids in succession.
>
> In general we handle binary diffs by first caching the object ids from the "index" line and using those if we then find an indication that the diff is binary.
>
> The input could contain patches generated with "[`git diff --binary`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0df19eb9d905ff9b6115139106d98d8f0a8a9046/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup>".
> This currently breaks the parse logic and results in multiple patch-ids output for a single commit.
> Here we have to skip the contents of the patch itself since those do not go into the patch id.
> `--binary` implies `--full-index` so the object ids are always available.
>
> When the diff is generated with `--full-index` there is no patch content to skip over.
>
> When a diff is generated without `--full-index` or `--binary`, it will contain abbreviated object ids.
> This will still result in a sufficiently unique patch-id when hashed, but does not match internal patch id output.
> We'll call this OK for now as we already need specialized arguments to diff in order to match internal patch id (namely `-U3`).