# Git command to find backported commits in Linux Kernel Repo

Tags: git, version-control, linux-kernel

Consider the Linux Kernel Git repository. The new versions of the kernel contain the backport of upstream fixes. E.g. [v4.3.4](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.3.4) and [v4.1.16](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.1.16) both contain the commit 23567fd052a9abb6d67fe8e7a9ccdd9800a540f2.

However, backporting that commit to those branches was itself a new commit, c23d6de841098d408ceb573cbc9f4dcf7c92a786 for 4.3.4 and b71567e6c9a2b15b7be9cb8ca695e9c990c0513b for 4.1.16.
As far as i can see, the ID of the original commit (23567fd0..) is now only part of the comment in those new commits.

Is there a (series of) git commands, that allow me to get a list of all the branches that contain a commit message which contains a specific commit ID?

Comment: A combination of `git for-each-ref` and `git rev-list --grep=<commit-ID>` should do the trick.

Comment: I am quite the git novice, would you mind making an example?

Comment: it is not working, it just explains the usage of the  rev-list comand

Comment: Hash of backported commits is not the same, moreover the contents also not the same (commit message and changes themselves). So, this task quite non-trivial.

Comment: You write: [...] get a list of all the branches [...]. However, the [Linux-kernel repo](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) has only one branch: `master`. Do you want to list tags instead?