# git merge --rebase: how to find "former/previous sha1"

Tags: git

Imagine I have branch `develop` and branch `feature`

On `feature` there's a commit `shaX`

Someone merged `develop` on `feature` with `--rebase` and pushed, thus the feature commit is `shaY` now and history has been rewritten.

Currently, I only have `shaY`. But I'd like to recreate the original `feature` branch from `shaX`.

How can I get `shaX` when I only know `shaY`?

---

I can (if required) accept a solution done on the computer of the dev that made the bad merge, but would prefer a solution that could be done on any machine (if possible), for my own knowledge, and because that developer could be gone or his machine destroyed

Comment: Don't you use any internal Id for tracking, Something like Bug ID?

Comment: @Dinidu we use github issues but what's your point?

Comment: some options here perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304574/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-an-equivalent-commit/26090892#26090892

Comment: On "any machine": not possible. On the machine that did the rebase, you can have a look in `git reflog [ref]` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As [Mort said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809164/git-merge-rebase-how-to-find-former-previous-sha1#comment80573740_46809164), you cannot necessarily do this on *any* machine.

Really, we must consider not *machines* but rather *repositories*.  The question becomes: which set of repositories has or had *X*, and how do we find it?  It doesn't matter too much what we call this ("who" or "what" or "repositories" or whatever) as long as we keep in mind that once we find this set, it's really a list of individual repositories.

#### Who has a commit?

Since Git is distributed, there may be many copies of the repository.  Each copy is potentially a little bit different.  *Some* number of copies—although the number could be *zero*—*will* have the original commit, and some *won't*.  The reason the first number could be zero is just what you said:

> ... that developer could be gone or his [copy] destroyed

If he was the only one with a viable copy, and it's now gone, you're down to zero copies of the original and out of luck.  But since he did the original operation in his Git repository, we know he must have, at some point, had the original commit with hash *X*.  So the question expands to: who else—what other repositories—might have *X?*  Second, for those that might have it, how do we find it?

The answer to the first question starts with this: *Anyone who picked it up, had it at some point.  If so, they may still have it.  If not, they obviously do not have it.*

The way most people pick up commits, in general, is by running `git fetch`.  (Note that `git clone` is a wrapper that, once it's created a new repository, runs `git fetch`, so even `git clone` is a case of `git fetch`.)  When you run `git fetch`, you instruct your Git to connect to another Git.  Your Git asks the other Git: *What branch and tag names do you have?*  Their Git sends yours a list, and your Git picks out the names it likes and asks their Git to send any *reachable* commits and other objects that go with those names, that your Git does not already have.

Once your Git has those objects, your Git takes those names and (typically) changes them in some way, and puts those names into your own repository.  If they have a branch named `feature`, your Git takes their name `feature` and turns it into your own name `origin/feature`.  Your Git then sets your own *reference* `refs/remotes/origin/feature` to the hash ID for the tip commit of their branch `feature`.

(For tag names, your own Git typically makes *no* change, which is why tag names are "more global" than branch names.)

Typically, most people running `git fetch` will bring either just one branch over—for instance, if I run `git pull origin master` (which runs `git fetch origin master`) I end up instructing my Git to connect to your Git, ask your Git what branches and tags and such you have, but then bring over only your `master` which I then call my `origin/master`—or to bring *all* branches over.  Therefore, any Git that ran `git fetch` to another Git that had the "good" commit under the name `feature` at the time, and brought over `feature`, will have brought over "good commit *X*".

This gives you the candidate pool: who might have picked up *X* originally?  Anyone who ran `git fetch` (including the `git fetch`-es run by `git clone` and `git pull`, though the latter tends to restrict the fetch) to a repository that had *X*, while that repository had *X*.

There's one more set of repositories to consider, because there's one other way to acquire a commit: `git push` can *send* a commit.  A `git push` operation is kind of like `git fetch`, except that the roles are reversed.  Instead of having my Git talk to your Git so that my Git can *get* commits from yours, I have my Git talk to your Git so that my Git can *give* commits to yours.  I offer the commit object(s) and any other object(s), and then I send a request: *Please set your branch or tag name, such as `refs/heads/feature`, to this hash ID.*  With `--force` I send a command: *Set your name to this hash ID!*  The force flag overrides the default "is a fast-forward" check done at the receiving end (but *not* any *other* checks enforced at the receiving end: the command can still be refused).

So anyone who received the good commit as a result of a `git push` could have it.  This *could* still be true even if a subsequent force-push overwrote the name that would lead to good commit *X*—but by default, it's not, for the reason given in the next section.

#### If you had *X*, do you still have *X*?

Now that we have all our candidate repositories lined up, we need to inspect them.  The place to look is in *reflogs*.  A *reflog* is what Git uses to retain a history of what happened to a reference.

We have, above, been using "reference" without properly defining it.  A reference is simply a name starting with `refs/`.  Git finds almost everything through these references.  Branch names, for instance, are references starting with `refs/heads/`, and tag names are references starting with `refs/tags/`.  Each reference stores a (single) hash ID.

Whenever you have your Git *update* a reference—replace the current hash ID with a new one—you have the option of having your Git *save* the *old* value, in a log entry.  These log entries are your *reflogs*.

Each reference has a reflog, and the special name `HEAD` also has a reflog.  Each reflog has a potentially-unlimited length—Git just adds to it on each reference-update—so to keep the reflogs from consuming infinite space, Git assigns every reflog entry a *time stamp* as well.  Reflog entries then eventually expire.

The expiration for any given reflog entry defaults to 30 or 90 days.  This part gets a bit tricky and I don't have time to write it up here, so let's just go with the shorter time, of 30 days.  While the reflog entry is alive, though, it retains the earlier hash IDs, and by retaining them, it keeps those objects "live" inside the repository database.

Meanwhile, there are two other tricky parts:

- Servers that accept `git push` requests will have reflogs *disabled* by default.  This makes them unlikely to retain good commit *X* if they have had a bad replacement pushed.
- Clients—the ones much more likely to have *X*—have been *renaming* `feature` to `origin/feature`.

Hence, the place to look to see if you can find the commit with good hash *X* is in the *reflogs*, probably those for `origin/feature`, on each of the clients that has been running `git fetch`.

The command to view the reflog, on any given Git repository, is `git reflog reference`.  (This actually runs `git log -g` so it's affected by user configuration `git log` options.)  Here's a snippet of `git reflog origin/master` and `git reflog origin/pu` on my copy of the Git repository for Git:

```
3dc57ebfb refs/remotes/origin/master@{2}: fetch: fast-forward

ca0964be6 refs/remotes/origin/pu@{1}: fetch: forced-update
```

I show these to illustrate the difference between a more normal fetch that brings in new commits *without* discarding old ones: `origin/master@{2}` points to commit `3dc57ebfb`, and when that update happened, it was a normal style update; but `origin/pu@{1}` points to `ca0964be6` and when that update happened, it was a "forced update".

If someone picked up good commit *X*, and then `feature` was rebased and force-pushed to `origin` and that someone picked up the new *bad* commit chain, their `origin/feature` will have experienced a forced update.  This means you will see a forced update in the reflog, which in turn means that the *earlier* reference has some chance of pointing to good commit *X*, or a commit whose history leads to good commit *X*.

Whether it actually points directly to *X* or to some descendant of *X* is a matter of chance, and you will have to inspect these commits manually to find out.

Comment: thanks :) The developer was able to recover his branch using his reflog. As far as I understand, it's impossible for me (who never pulled the branch) to recover from my own repository's reflog right?

Comment: Yes, if you never fetched it, then you won't have it. `pull` implies `fetch` (but limited—one of many reasons to avoid `pull`...).