# Finding cherry-picked or rebased commits using hash of the original commit

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, git-log, git-cherry-pick

I have a large git repo with many branches (normally, I work only with a small subset of them, related to features owned by my team). Suppose I have a hash of a commit (e.g. copied from a pull request). This commit might have been merged into one of the branches I am interested in, or not. It might have been merged directly, or cherry-picked or rebased. In the two latter cases its hash in the log is different (because it is now actually a brand new commit, although with the same diff).

Provided that I know the hash of the original commit, how can I find all branches that contain it directly or contain it either in cherry-picked or rebased form?

Comment: Similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605703/git-finding-duplicate-commits-by-patch-id. You can probably find what you need there.

Answer (score 2):

> Provided that I know the hash of the original commit, how can I find all branches that contain it directly or contain it either in cherry-picked or rebased form?

The good news is that you can definitely do all of this (under an assumption or two I will describe in a moment).  The *"contain it directly"* variant is the easiest: `git branch --contains hash` produces the answer.

The *"or ... in cherry-picked or rebase form* part is the one that requires an assumption, and the bad news is that the "how" part might be pretty messy.  Or it might be really easy!

There is a Git command, [`git patch-id`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id), that takes `git diff` output (as produced directly by `git diff`, or more conveniently by `git show`) and computes a *patch ID*, which is essentially a checksum of the diff after stripping out line numbers and white-space.  (For more, see the linked documentation page, or run `git help patch-id`.)  For instance:

```
$ git show HEAD | git patch-id
869f23f0e8b4813c88cb853fa2b4d415d25dc32c 8dca754b1e874719a732bc9ab7b0e14b21b1bc10
```

The second hash, if a second one appears, is the hash ID of the commit:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
8dca754b1e874719a732bc9ab7b0e14b21b1bc10
```

Hence, you can run `git show` on the original commit and get its patch ID, then run `git show` on each suspect commit and see if the patch ID matches.

That's the *hard* way (but easy enough to do for a single commit).  The *easy* way is to have Git tell you about "equal commits".  The [`git cherry`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry) command, and its more flexible but harder to use companion [`git rev-list --cherry-mark`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---cherry-mark), work by running `git show | git patch-id` on each commit in some set of commits, and `git show | git patch-id` on each commit in another set of commits, and telling you which commits in the first set match which ones in the second set.

To use `git rev-list`, you *must* choose a symmetric difference operation, i.e., use the `A...B` syntax with the three dots.  Git will compute the patch IDs of all the commits that are reachable from A but not B, and compare them to all the patch IDs of all the commits that are reachable from B but not A.  The `git cherry` command does much the same thing but with a different syntax and different output format.  Consult the two documentation pages for details.

The caveat is pretty obvious: the patch-ID is based on the diff minus line numbers and (some) white-space.  But sometimes during cherry-pick or rebase, the diff has to be *changed* to make it fit.  In this case, the patch IDs will not match, and this kind of detection will fail.  There is not much you can do about this.